# angular2 and charts.js interaction

Tags: javascript, angular, charts

I'm working currently with some charts from charts.js, i'm adding some simple interaction with them, when the user clicks a bar from a bar chart, a variable saves which bar was clicked.

This variable updates a line chart, this chart is updated with data previously saved in an array, so everytime the user clicks a different bar from the bar chart, the line chart should change.

My problem is that the variable doesn't change i get two different values.
By default the variable is initialized in 0.

Console log output:

```
from barchart click:3   
from change function:0 

from barchart click:2  
from change function:0
```

I print these lines from 2 different functions that happen at the same time.

This is function that should change the variable value when the bar chart is clicked on a bar.

```
  graphClickEvent(event:any, array:any){

    if(array[0]){

       this.offsetGraficas = array[0]._index;
     console.log("from barchart click:"+this.offsetGraficas);
    }

}
```

and this other function that happens at the same time:

```
changeHistorico(n:number) {
   console.log("from change function:"+this.offsetGraficas);

    this.show_historico = true;

    //some unrelated code goes here
}
```

from what i see, graphClickEvent is executed first, but i don't se any change in the variable.
Why it doesn't work as intended?

Comment: can you share you component complete code

Comment: is it possible that "this" in graphClickEvent and "this" in changeHistorico are different this?

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova actually yes, after reading the difference between angular2 this and javascript this, i solved the problem declaring offsetGraficas as a global variable and that worked

Comment: ok, i am adding the official answer now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like "this" in graphClickEvent and "this" in changeHistorico are different this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `this` from within a click event is different from the `this` of the parent component.
Global variable is a way.

But a better solution would be to pass the component instance is the config of the chart.js graph.

```
this.dsChart2 = new Chart(myCtx2,{
  type: 'pie',
  parentInstance: this,
  data: { ... }
  options:{
    onClick: this.graphClickEvent
  }
}
```

Now when the `graphClickEvent` is called, you get two values, event and the chart Instance, from which you are already getting the index value.

So now from within the click event function, you can reference the `parentInstance`, as follows:

```
graphClickEvent(evt,item) {
  console.dir(item);
  let parentThis = item[0]['_chart']['config']['parentInstance'];
  // here parentThis is the component this or $scope
  parentThis.variable = value;
}
```

Comment: The real answer. You saved my life.